# JavaScript do not allow dot as first when highlighted and inserted

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to validate the input field that is only for numbers and decimals. But the dot can't be first! All works fine except when someone select/highlight the input value and hit dot then the dot is added as first. Try highlighting 0 and click dot(.) it will let you insert it as first. Any idea?

```js
function isNumberKey(evt, obj) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
  var value = obj.value;
  var dotcontains = value.indexOf(".") != -1;  
  if ((value.length==0) && (event.keyCode==46)) return false; // checking that length ==0 than not allow to enter '.'
  if (dotcontains)
    if (charCode == 46) return false;                                  
  if (charCode == 46) return true;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;                  
  return true;
}
```

```html
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" VALUE="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,this)">
```

Comment: In fact, writing .5 as decimal is absolutly valid (0.5 = .5)

Comment: Yes, but I want to prevent users sending only the dot.

Comment: Maybe detect the absence of a leading 0 and add it in for them? Might be a better user experience

Comment: @chazsolo, hm maybe, how would I do it?

Comment: `<input onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/^\./,'')">`

Comment: You could add a `pattern` attribute to validate against numbers and the period, and in your event callback check whether or not the first character is a `.` - if so, add a `0` at the start (I'm not posting this as an answer yet since its different than the question your asking, just a suggestion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your `value.length==0` check isn't applying is because your previous value (0) made the length 1. But you could expand this idea, and check to see if the portion being edited *starts with* position 0.

```
if (evt.target.selectionStart === 0 && (evt.keyCode==46)) return false;
```

This will catch both a highlighted section being edited that starts with the first position, as well as the cursor just being there.

https://jsfiddle.net/nyzkdb81/9/

Comment: Happy to help. Note there was a typo earlier where the second 'evt' was written as 'event'. It still worked, but it should be changed.